# Issue with reproducing the results of a cURL command in code

Tags: c#, curl, .net-4.5

I am trying to do the following using .NET

What would the C# code look like using HttpClient, if my username is `test` and password is `password`?

```
HTTP Method: GET
URL: http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories
Sample command:
curl --digest -u{username}:{password} http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories
```

Here is what I have but I don't get the html:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();

 var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("-u", "{test}:{password}") });

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    "http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories", requestContent);

 // Get the response content.
 HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

 var blah = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: What have you tried with C# already? Please give it a shot and then let us know if you run into problems.

Comment: Zoinky, gimme-teh-codez posts are not popular on SO. Please try something before posting a question like this. Please delete this question and come back when you have some code to share.

Comment: @PaulSasik Don't encourage people to delete and then repost the same question.  They should be editing the question to fix it, not reposting it over and over again.

Comment: I agree with you in general @Servy but IMO this is a special case. I suggested a delete because the post got seven down votes and was closed/put on hold very quickly. After such a negative reaction even a great job of editing is much less likely to get traction.

Comment: @PaulSasik Constantly deleting and re-asking the same question is a fast track to a question ban.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add (new Uri ("http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com"), "Digest",  new NetworkCredential ("username", "passwd"));
```

After that construct the `HttpClient` with the credential cache:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient( new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credCache});
```

Rest of the process is same. If you perform http `POST` then use `PostAsync`, and for http `GET` use `GetAsync`.

You'll find more detail about [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).